# Is it possible to give users view access to a master object without giving it to details of the master object?

Tags: sharing, master-detail

I'm dealing with a request to make Accounts visible to all users. However, we have a custom object which is in a master-detail relationship with accounts. This custom object should not be visible to all users, but should have certain criteria for who can see it.

I don't believe it's possible to give view access to Accounts without also giving view access to this custom object. The only way I can see which **might** be possible is through the Object Settings at the profile level, checking View All on Accounts while leaving it unchecked on the custom object. However, in testing, this doesn't seem to be working.

Is there any way to accomplish this or should I answer that it's impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct that a Detail side of the Master Detail inherits its visibility from the Master object.

Individual fields could be hidden and it could be possible to restrict this by using page layouts and profiles so it was not immediately visible as a related list from the Account page and to put a custom tab for the Detail object as hidden for particular user profiles.

Unfortunately though a search that matches fields on the Detail object would mean it was visible to any user profile that was making the search.

If you can use a lookup field instead then it will still have the parent/child relationship but allow the use of the profile to restrict visibility of the child object.